# Defining a application settings path

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program on C# and i'm saving Username and Password in my Project Propetie Settings.

Like this:

```
Settings.Default.Username = this.txtUsername.Text;
Settings.Default.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

It works like it should however If I start the Program from the Desktop and save my Propeties and re-open it on the Desktop it's saved. If I open the file on Desktop, save it and re-open it on another Path the Propeties are "resetted".

How come? Can't I set a path to the Settings File? So it wouldn't reset all the time I move the Executeable File?

> "Hey Program, look up your App.config on C:\Program
>   Files(MyProgram)\Settings"

?

Comment: what is your Settings Scope set to `Application`..? if so change it to `User`

Comment: Side note: saving passwords in plain text is bad idea, so I assume you just pick random fields as sample.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know right, gonna work it out somewhere later.